# phpsec and zend framework 2 should be integrated?

Tags: php, security, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm writing a web application based on Zend Framework 2.

Now I've found http://phpsec.owasp.org/ and I'm wondering if I need to integrate Zend Framework 2 with phpsec (to enhance the Zend Framework 2 security) or if Zend Framework already use phpsec (or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

What you have asked is more of a subjective question. My opinion is that you do not need an additional layer of security on top of what ZF already has. And that is the case for many frameworks - we use them because there are some basic functionalities built-in to them (in varying levels of complexity, of course) and security is one of them. You need stuff like phpsec when you want to add a layer of security on top of a custom codebase that might not have one already. Having said that you might want to compare what is in ZF and phpsec and add the ones that might be missing in ZF, since phpsec is a decoupled set of security functionalities.

Also, these are two good articles to understand and leverage security in ZF, one is from [IBM - Improve web security in ZF](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-zend-security/index.html) and the other is from [Zend - Building Security in ZF](http://www.zend.com/topics/Building-secure-app-using-ZF2.pdf)